# CSS Flexbox with position absolute confusion

Tags: css

I'm confused how this works could someone walk me through what exactly happened?

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.chat-break {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 20px;

}

.chat-break .line {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 100%;
}

.chat-break .date {
  color: #B5B5B5;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-break">
    <div class="line">
    </div>
    
    <p class="date">Today</p>
</div>
```

My understanding:

- `.chat-break` flexbox has two elements `.line` and `.date`.
- ...but after using `position: absolute` on `.date` its no longer its own element inside the flexbox?
- Then why is "Today" being centered on the line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Preface:

- The `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` properties are collectively referred to as "box inset" properties.
- Keep in mind that all CSS properties that aren't explicitly set will have default values that are either "`initial`" values or *inherited* values.

  - So unless explicitly specified otherwise, every element has `position: static;`.
  - [The `initial` value for all of the box-inset properties is `auto`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#propdef-top), *regardless* of their element's `position` and `display` property.

    - But the *behaviour* of the `auto` value does depend on the element's `position` and/or *formatting context*.
- CSS has a lot of surprising and counter-intuitive behaviour.

  - This is not intentional, but a consequence of how CSS evolved over time over the past ~25 years it's existed.

    - Originally CSS wasn't capable of any layout control at all, it was only useful for things like font and text styling.
    - In fact, CSS's main layout features (like `flex`, `grid`, etc) weren't added (let alone supported by browsers) until well into the 2010s.

      - For example, [the original 2008 spec for flex was abandoned. It was reinvented in 2011](https://medium.com/@BennyOgidan/history-of-css-grid-and-css-flexbox-658ae6cfe6d2), and [not widely supported until 2014](https://caniuse.com/flexbox).

#### Why `<div class="line">` fills the width of the page:

- `<div class="chat-break">` has `display: flex;`, which makes it a **flex-parent**.

  - All immediate child elements (with certain exceptions) of a flex-parent, that have `position: static`, are **flex-items**.
  - Therefore`<div class="line">` is a flex-item.
  - Therefore`<p class="date">` is **not** a flex-item because it has `position: absolute;`.

    - (Generally speaking) elements with `position: absolute;` are **not subject to their layout-container's layout rules** and are re-positioned with absolute-coordinates where the origin is in *their-closet-ancestor-element-without-`position: static;`* (yes, that's a mouthful).

      - This is why `position: relative;` is being applied to `<div class="chat-break">`.
- Therefore `<div class="chat-break">` is a flex-parent **with only one flex-item**, despite having two element children.

  - And because it has `justify-content: center;` it means that its single flex-item (`<div class="line">`) will be centered.
- *Also*, because `<div class="chat-break">` has `display: flex;` (rather than `display: inline-flex`) it means that `<div class="chat-break">` is a **block-level element**, so it fills the width of its container, which is `<body>`, which fills the width of the viewport.

  - And because `<div class="line">` also has `width: 100%;` (which becomes `flex-basis: 100%;`) it means the `<div class="line">` will fill the width of `<div class="chat-break">`.
  - Therefore `<body>`, `<div class="chat-break">`, and `<div class="line">` (in that order) will fill the width of the viewport.

#### Why `<p class="date">` is centered:

- As `<p class="date">` uses `auto` for all its *box inset* properties (i.e. `top`, `right`, etc) with `position: absolute;` then the *computed value* of those properties is the same **as if** `<p class="date">` was `position: static;`.

  - However, *if* `<p class="date">` was `position: static;` then it would be a flex-item and would share its flex row with `<div class="line">` - which would mean it would be located *somewhere off to the right* of the line (due to `justify-content: center;`).

    - But it's actually centered, because this is a special-case scenario that's *specifically specified in the specification*...

      > https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items
      >
      > ### 4.1. Absolutely-Positioned Flex Children
      >
      > As it is out-of-flow, an absolutely-positioned child of a flex container does not participate in flex layout.
      >
      > The `static` position of an `absolute`ly-positioned child of a `flex` container **is determined such that the child is positioned as if it were the sole flex item in the flex container**, assuming both the child and the flex container were fixed-size boxes of their used size. For this purpose, auto margins are treated as zero.

It's well-worth reading the rest of the section as it also covers other brain-stretching scenarios, like "what if `align-self: center;` is used"?